# Not binding first time to dropdown

Tags: c#, enums

I have a drop down list for country and states.

And while binding the items on first time is not adding but in the second refresh page then it is selecting in the drop down values.

Code:

not in the page load some button click event fires then needs to show the corresponding values.

```
this.BindCountries();
ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value = objAddressResponse.Country;
this.BindStates(objAddressResponse.Country);
ddlState.SelectedItem.Value = 
          ddlState.Items.Count > 1 ? objAddressResponse.State : "";
```

How to bind in the first time itself?

Comment: the above code is assigning the values to the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand your code; Following is the a basic code for binding a drop down list to a data source.

```
ddl.DataTextField = "fieldName1";  //field name for Text
ddl.DataValueField = "fieldName2"; //field name for Value
ddl.DataSource = yourDataSource; //your data source with above field names
ddl.DataBind(); //bind the data source here

//Edit: Selecting a value.
if(ddl.Items.FindByValue("yourValue") !=null){
   ddl.Items.FindByValue("yourValue").Seleted = true;
}
```

Comment: after binding the values to the drop down the values from the database or any other that needs to show as the selected value

Comment: yeah got it but can't we make the condition in a single line?